# while loop not giving me the predicted result

Tags: java

I am working on a small project to learn java. I'm currently working on creating a loop that accomplishes an rpg like combat experience. The loop works correctly the first time through, but the second time through does not.
Here is the relevant code

```
int dummyhp = 10;

int Cweap = in.nextInt();
if (Cweap == 1){
    System.out.println("You pick up the dagger and Lunge at the dummy");

     while(dummyhp >0){
        int Ddamage = (c1.speed-6)*5;

        if (Ddamage <= 4){ 
            System.out.println ("You fall over a chair, luckily you graze the dummy on your way down");
            dummyhp--;
            System.out.println(dummyhp + "hp left");
        }
        else if ( Ddamage == 5){
            System.out.println("you get in a good hit");
            dummyhp = dummyhp - 3;
            System.out.println(dummyhp + "hp left");
        }
        else if (Ddamage > 6)
            System.out.println(" you cut the dummys head clean off" );

        dummyhp = dummyhp-10;
        System.out.println(dummyhp + "hp left");
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant output that I get.

You pick up the dagger and Lunge at the dummy
you get in a good hit
7hp left
-3hp left

I'm unsure why the Ddamage variable = 5 the first time through and changes to being greater than 6 the second time through.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post full clean output. Also Ddamage is based on c1.speed which is not visible from the code.

Comment: `Ddamage = (c1.speed-6)*5` so Ddamage value depends on `c1.speed` - where does it come from, where is its value changed or calculated, etc...

Comment: y'all, can you not down vote a question from someone who is new to SO. Seriously, learn some basic human friendly skills. Anyway, it is hard to tell how ur Ddamage is being calculated as we don't know what speed is for c1.speed

Comment: Java is not Python, here indentation doesn't describe scope, `{...}` does. You forgot to add to your last `else if` with proper `{....}` which means code `dummyhp = dummyhp-10; System.out.println(dummyhp + "hp left");` will be executed in each iteration, not only if last condition is met. Voting to close as simple typo.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! Pshemo hit it spot on!

Answer (score 1):

you did not put curly braces in the last else-if statement reason for the else-if structure to only execute the

```
System.out.println(" you cut the dummys head clean off" );
```

and whole while-loop body to execute the

```
dummyhp = dummyhp-10;
System.out.println(dummyhp + "hp left");
```

which results for while-loop executing only once .
If you want to execute all these three statement in the else-if statement you should do this in your last else-if statement for the last else-if to execute all these statement and not only the println() method.

```
else if(Ddamage > 6)
{
System.out.println(" you cut the dummys head clean off" );
dummyhp = dummyhp-10;
System.out.println(dummyhp + "hp left");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time you change Ddamage is when the loop starts. So if you solve (c1.speed-6)*5>6 you will know that c1.speed > 7.2. Therefore when Ddamage is set the second time, it is set to a value greater than 7.2. The reason it's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve is because we can't tell what c1.speed is.